# serialize models method with parameter in django REST API error " Object of type method is not JSON serializable "

Tags: python, django, rest

how to serialize a models function with parameter . ? when i try this get an error . like this :
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

  def likes_exist(self,user):
        liked = ""
        for i in self.likes.all():
            if i.user == user:
                liked = liked

            else:
                liked = not liked
        return liked
 

class LikePost(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='news_likes')
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def post(request):
  id = request.data["id"]
  user = Customer.objects.filter(id=id)
  post_object = Post()
  post_object.likes_exist(user)
  return PostSerializer #something else
```

Serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields  = ["title","likes_exist"]
```

error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 100, in render
    ret = json.dumps(
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/shamsucm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 67, in default
    return super().default(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable
```

how to fix this error . ? why is this error ?

Thank you

Comment: can you share the full error trace

Comment: yeah , i updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create `liked` variable globally in your `Post` model class
And in `PostSerilaizer` Meta class add `liked` field instead of `likes_exist`

Comment: not working bro . in this case the global variable value is returning . i think the condition is not working / checking in this case .